# Saving image from gmail app

Tags: gmail

I have downloaded some images from an email using my gmail app . I tried to find it in my gallery and also in my storage but i couldn't find it either in my gallery or in my storage

Comment: I've cleaned up the remaining comments here, glad to see it was resolved and the answer posted.  In the future, please use [chat] for extended discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gmail app go to settings, then click on your your target email address (where you want to get image attachments downloaded) , then untick the option which says "Auto download attachment to recent messages via Wi-Fi" try again to get your image.

It seems attachment downloads are restricted to wi-fi (default) but option is not clear at all as it seems to imlply a different thing. So disabling this option implies both data and wi-fi are considered (although the option is a bit misleading) It however fixed the issue.

Edit

Downloaded images are saved in downloads folder of sdcard or here `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

credits: beeshyams